# Create list of elements with dependence on a variable

Tags: variable-definitions

I'm aware that we can make a list of elements:

```
x = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString@i], {i, n}];
```

This returns x = {x1,x2,x3} when n = 3. What I want is to be able to turn each of these variables x1,x2,x3 into functions of t (e.g. I want y = {x1[t],x2[t],x3[t]}).

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Look up [`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through): ``Through @ x[t]``

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Indexed variables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html) are usually much easier to work with.

```
Format[x[n_Integer]] := Subscript[x, n]

Format[a[n_Integer]] := Subscript[a, n]

X[t_, n : _Integer?Positive : 3] := Array[x[#][t] &, n]
```

Using default value for `n`

```
X[t]
```

[image]

Specifying a value for `n`

```
X[t, 5]
```

[image]

```
X[t, 5].Array[a, 5]
```

[image]